# Using if with Scanner in Java isn't working properly when comparing strings

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Sept1Little {
    public static void main (String args []) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hey! I'm not gonna program today o.o but I'm gonna do a little program :3");
        System.out.println("Let's play with some math!");
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers and magic will happen");
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        float a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        float b = s.nextFloat();
        float c = (float) Math.pow( a, b);
        System.out.printf("The number is :%f\n" , c);
        System.out.println("We love Bernie Sanders!");
        System.out.println("Come on, let's push him over the line!");
        int poll1 = 30;
        System.out.println("Current poll amount: " + poll1);
        System.out.println("Let's add 7% and an extra 1%!");
        int poll2 = poll1 + 7;
        int poll3 = ++poll2;
        System.out.println("Bernie Sanders would get :" + poll3 + ". Bernie would get a better percentage than Hillo Clinto-Money");
        System.out.println("Write in the best US President Nominee: ");
        String president = Keyboard.readString();
        if (president.equals("Bernie Sanders")){
            System.out.println("You chose Bernie Sanders.");

        }
        else if (president.equals("Donald Trump")) {
            System.out.println("You chose Donald Trump");

        }
        else if (president.equals("Hillary Clinton")) {
            System.out.println("You chose Hillary Clinton ");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Choose someone we know...");

        }
        System.out.println("Let's calculate how much money you owe the govt by... SQUARE ROOTING IT!");
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of money you owe the govt: ");
        float debt1 = Keyboard.readFloat();
        System.out.printf("The amount is now :%f\n" , Math.sqrt(debt1));
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Euro to Dollar Convertor!");
        System.out.print("Enter the amount in US Dollars you wish to convert to Euro: ");
        float euro1 = Keyboard.readFloat();
        final float rate = (float) 1.13;
        System.out.printf("The amount in Euro is %f\n" , euro1 / rate);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using `Keyboard.readString();` when I ask for the nominee. When I use `s.readLine();`, it doesn't work, it skips to the `else` clause and then it crashes since it takes the president input for the `float` value afterwards. I'm sorry that it is a bit political but I didn't bother fiddling with it. When I put `"Bernie Sanders"` as `"BernieSanders"`, I don't get the error, anyone knows why?

Comment: Is `Keyboard` a class you created?

Comment: If you're using a Scanner for user input, stick with the same Scanner for **all** user input.

Comment: Keyboard is a classs I copied

Comment: I tried the same thing only using Scanner

Comment: Do what @HovercraftFullOfEels said and put `.useDelimiter("\n");` at end of  the `...new Scanner...` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that it is because `s.nextFloat();` and `s.nextInt();` only reads the `float` and the `int`, respectively, not the full line so the cursor of the `Scanner` it's after the float or the int and not in the next line. Here an example:

If your input it's:

```
5 Bench
Prove
```

And you have in your code:

```
a= s.nextInt(); //5
b= s.nextLine(); //" Bench"
```

Why it isn't catching the `Prove` value? Because after using `s.nextInt()` the cursor of the `Scanner` it's after the `5` and not in the next line (the line in which we have `Prove`). To avoid it you have to read the rest of the line (useless for you because you don't want it) but without getting this value. Like this:

```
a= s.nextInt(); //5
s.nextLine(); //We go to the next line
b= s.nextLine(); //"Prove"
```

**P.S.:** You have to use `s.nextLine();` each time you use a `s.nextInt();` or `s.nextFloat();` as the example that I put above.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: I have tried putting s.nextLine(); after the if statements, the else statement and after both. Still the same problem.

Comment: @AuroraRossi You don't have to put them after `if` statements. Just after `nextInt()` and `nextFloat()` methods.

Comment: @AuroraRossi: then you're doing it wrong. Show us by editing your original question and adding the changed code at the bottom.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean? Put the full code of Aurora replacing what I put in the example above?

Comment: @AuroraRossi: you're telling us that you're making some changes but that they don't work. We have absolutely no idea what changes you've made or how it doesn't work. I'm asking you to simply show us.

Comment: Oh sorry @HovercraftFullOfEels I though you were referring to me when you put the comment instead of Aurora. My mistake :S

Comment: Error -- my comment had a @ Aurora's name at its lead, so it should be unambiguous who I was directing it at. Nice answer BTW, 1+.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes I know but I think I get confused because it appeared on my mailbox :D. And thanks! ;)